# What does ?= mean in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

May I know what `?=` means in a regular expression? For example, what is its significance in this expression:

```
(?=.*\d).
```

Comment: Tip of the day: to search for special characters there is http://symbolhound.com

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`?=` is a positive lookahead, a type of [zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). What it's saying is that the captured match must be followed by whatever is within the parentheses but that part isn't captured.

Your example means the match needs to be followed by zero or more characters and then a digit (but again that part isn't captured).

Comment: Thanks cletus. Searching for information on this was not easy with a typical search engine :).

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Lookarounds".

Comment: What do the words in the last parenthesis means, please? "but again that part is not captured". Does it mean that when I call a function, let's say, `match()`, it will match me certain string but the matched strings that will be returned does not include the characters "excluded" by `?=`?

Comment: @theraneman https://www.google.com/search?q=?= returns this questions as the second hit now :)

Answer (score 17):

(?=pattern) is a zero-width positive lookahead assertion.
For example, `/\w+(?=\t)/` matches a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in `$&`.

Answer (score 14):

The below expression will find the last number set in a filename before its extension (excluding dot (.)).

```
'\d+(?=\.\w+$)'
```

*file4.txt* will match **4**.

*file123.txt* will match **123**.

*demo.3.js* will match **3** and so on.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder An example makes it easier to understand. What's wrong with politely suggesting that this be added as a comment?