# Using ?=. in regular expression

Tags: regex

I saw the phrase

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9_#@%\*\-]{8,24}$
```

in regex, which was password checking mechanism. I read few courses about regular expressions, but I never saw combination `?=.` explained.

I want know how it works. In the example it is searching for at least one capital letter, one small letter and one number. I guess it's something like "if".

Comment: [Positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: If you want to know what regular expression characters mean, enter the regexp at regexr.com. Then hover the mouse over the characters and it will display the meaning in a tooltip.

Comment: You might also find an explanation at http://regex101.com/

Comment: Note in particular that the `.` is unrelated to the `(?=`. Your regex starts with `(?=` (ensure that you can see, but don't consume) followed by `.*` (zero or more of any character).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ?= mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570896/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`(?=regex_here)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It is a zero-width assertion, meaning that it matches a location that is followed by the regex contained within `(?=` and `)`. To quote from the linked page:

> lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match,
> returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are
> called "assertions". They do not consume characters in the string, but
> only assert whether a match is possible or not. Lookaround allows you
> to create regular expressions that are impossible to create without
> them, or that would get very longwinded without them.

The `.` is not part of the lookahead, because it matches any single character that is not a line terminator.

Comment: I did not downvote you. anyway it doesnt seem to work in javascript,to bad.

Comment: Best explanation I found, and I read 4 or 5 webpages.

Answer (score 4):

Although i am a newbie to regex but what i understand about the above regex is

1- ?= is positive lookahead i.e. it matches the expression by looking ahead and sees if there is any pattern that matches your search paramater like [A-Z]

2- .* makes sure that they can be 0 or more number of characters before your matching expression i.e. it makes sure that u can lookahead till the end of the input string to find a match.
In short * is a quantifier which says 0 or more so if:

> **For instance u changed * with ? for [A-Z] part then your expression will only return true if ur 1st or 2nd letter is capital. OR if u changed it with + then ur expression will return true if any letter other than the first is a capital letter**

Answer (score 1):

^ asserts position at start of the string
Positive Lookahead (?=\D*\d)
Assert that the Regex below matches
\D matches any character that's not a digit (equivalent to [^0-9])

- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
  Positive Lookahead (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])
  Assert that the Regex below matches
  Match a single character not present in the list below [^a-z]
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
  Match a single character present in the list below [a-z]
  a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
  Positive Lookahead (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])
  Assert that the Regex below matches
  Match a single character not present in the list below [^A-Z]
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
  Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
  A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
  . matches any character (except for line terminators)
  {8,30} matches the previous token between 8 and 30 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)