# Repeat Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that checks if every - in the string has a letter before and after it.

I got this so far:

```
(([-])?[a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]+[-]+[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+$|[a-zA-Z ]+$)|([a-zA-Z ])
```

works for these examples:

- Tester
- tester_test
- Tes ter_te st

It doesn't work for these examples:

- Tester_test tester_test
- te st_te_st_te_st

Comment: That `regex` looks __much too__ complex for relatively simple matching. Consider simplifying it.

Comment: Please could you elaborate what exactly you are trying to match?

Comment: What does it mean, "does not work"? how is it failing? what do you want to do?

Comment: I want it to work for all examples.

Comment: Every - in the string needs to have a letter before and after it.

Comment: Which flavour of regex?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by flavour for regex.
I am using it for a ASP.NET element.

Comment: You can check for matches of `[^a-Z][-][^a-Z]` and if found, you have the negative result.

Comment: What exactly is your purpose here? To capture words that contain underscores that are *not* surrounded by letters, or that *only* have "correct" underscores in them? Some context of what your actually doing this for would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that every underscore is surrounded by a letter, you can use

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])_(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F4JgTSo-HebCIYT8)

This demo works for all of your inputs.

This uses a [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672) (`(?<=...)`) and [lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570916) (`(?=...)`).

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. There is a section on lookarounds that may be of interest, as well as a list of online testers at the bottom.

Comment: What does ?<= mean? I don't find anything about this in google.

Comment: @Xatenev: Updated my answer. They're the lookaheads and behinds I mentioned.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Comment: This is structurally one of the best regex related answers I have seen in a while! Sadly debuggex only supports javascript, python and perl. The ASP.NET syntax might be different and the lookahead feature might not even exist there - I dont know. @eXo the mentioned FAQ is really helpful, go check it out.

Comment: It works for me at regexhero, which is an online tester for .NET regular expressions: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=35632c5b-ccbd-430b-a8e5-97f833b1b08f. @eXo: Are you going to give us some more information so we can help you better, or are you just going to throw error-messages at us?

Answer (score 1):

This regex seemed to work for all your Examples, and aswell as alot of others. 
Check for the negation of following:

```
^(.*(([^a-zA-Z]-)|(-[^a-zA-Z])).*)$
```

Check this regex out here, with a lot of examples:

http://www.rubular.com/r/o2OZYJheIt

Comment: I thought the requirements were that a letter needs to be on *both* sides of the underscore/dash. Meaning `a-a` is okay, and `a--a`, `a-`, and `$-` are not.

Comment: I dont think ruby is used by the questioner.

Comment: @SebastianH the Regex is quite similiar to his probably. Regex doesn't change thaat much.