# What is the following token pattern matching: [A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\\s+)

Tags: regex

I understand the meaning of `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` corresponding to a repeated sequence of one or more characters containing upper case letters, lower case letters, digits and underscores, but what does the whole expression corresponds to?

Comment: That depends on to what text you are applying the regex.

Comment: `(?=\\s+)` means lookahead for a literal backslash, followed by repeated `s`s. (or if that's meant to be a single backslash, then lookahead for repeated space characters. In other words, word characters followed by spaces?)

Comment: Unless that regex was declared in a string @CertainPerformance. Then it could possibly be inferred as word characters followed by multiple spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ?= mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570896/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your regex is `/[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\s+)/` and that your programming language requires you to escape the `\` as `\\`.

Like you said, `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` matches one or more alpha-numeric characters.

The `(?=)` pattern indicates a [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expression. We are checking if after the alpha-numeric characters, we have one or more(`+`) whitespace(`\s`) characters. However, the difference between `/[A-Za-z0-9_]+\s+/` and `/[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\s+)/` is that the former would include the whitespace in the match while the latter will not.

If you run your regex on `this_is_followed_by_whitespace␠␠␠` where "␠" indicates spaces, only `this_is_followed_by_whitespace` will be matched. The expression is just looking ahead to check whether there is whitespace. Running `/[A-Za-z0-9_]+\s+/` on the same string would match `this_is_followed_by_whitespace␠␠␠`.

Play around with your regex on [this RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/3t7g8).