# regex101 - match all occurrences of a string only in the first line where it is found

Tags: regex

In regex101 site I have the text:

```
text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3

text1 text2 text1 text2 text1 text2

text1 text2 text1 text2 text1 text2

text1 text2 text1 text2 text1 text2
```

I want to match all `text2` but only in the first line where it is found:

```
text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3

text1 **text2** text1 **text2** text1 **text2**

text1 text2 text1 text2 text1 text2

text1 text2 text1 text2 text1 text2
```

How do I get this?

Comment: Loop over the lines. Test if the line matches `text2`. If it does, return all the matches. Then break out of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the question, I have need to do this in regex101 site.

Comment: That's just a testing site, why do you need to do it there?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single regexp. You need a negative lookbehind that matches a previous row containing `text2`. But this requires a variable-length lookbehind, and most engines don't allow this.

Comment: It doesn't matter why I want to do it there for the purpose of solving my question.

Comment: This site is for discussing programming. Programming is done using programming languages. And this is easy to do in most programming languages, even if you can't do it in a single regexp on the testing site.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with regex flavours like PCRE, which support an end-of-match token (`\G`) and can be set to single line matching (`/s`). The idea is to match the first target by anchoring to the beginning of the line while consuming as few characters as possible (`^.*?`) and then to allow further matches only at the end of previous matches, while excluding line breaks in procuring them (`\G[^\r\n]*?`). See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZcqJmi/1).

An expression to do that could look like this:

```regex
/(?:^.*?|\G[^\r\n]*?)\Ktext2/gs
```

`\K` is simply used to cut out the preceeding part of matches from the result to avoid using capturing groups for singling out `text2`.

To cover other aspects of line break/position matching, if you want to drop the single-line modifier (`/s`), in which case `.` ceases to match new-line characters, you can use a class that also matches line breaks, like `[\s\S]*?`, instead of `.*?` to get the initial match. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vimFiM/1).

```regex
/(?:^[\s\S]*?|\G[^\r\n]*?)\Ktext2/g
```

If you want to use the multi-line modifier `/m` specifically, in which case the caret `^` now matches at the beginning of every line, you'll have to use the anchor for the beginning of string `\A` instead to match the initial target. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iLqIIR/1).

```regex
/(?:\A[\s\S]*?|\G[^\r\n]*?)\Ktext2/gm
```

Comment: With PCRE, in singleline mode, it's possible to avoid `[^\r\n]` with `\N`: https://regex101.com/r/s742A5/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm actually not sure about the behaviour of `\N`. Presumably, when the line ending is defined as `CR`, `\N` would not match it. If, however, the line ending was defined as `CRLF` - as in Windows - wouldn't `\N` match `CR` and only leave out `LF`? See [FULL STOP (PERIOD, DOT) AND \N](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC7).

Comment: If you are unsure about dots, newline sequences, etc. , play with that: https://3v4l.org/vWQtc#v8.2.6

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the demo; very nifty, I'll probably steal that. With that in mind, I would not replace `[^\r\n]` with `\N`, since `\N` matches `\r` if the line type is `LF` (which might be the default) and no line setting modifier is used to explicitly accept `CR` or `CRLF` as newline.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using trick with capturing groups inside of lookahead (and disabled global flag of course).

Your regex would this:

```
text2(?=(?:.*?(text2))*)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PHFfRN/1)

Notice that if you have more than two separate matching elements, you'll need to select .Net ending, as only it will allow multiple captures for the same group.

Comment: What is the difference between () and (?=)?

Comment: `()` - capturing group, matches inner pattern and keeps matched string ing group with corresponding number, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127). `(?=)` - positive lookahead, checks that current position followed by something, that is matching content of said lookahead. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570916).

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, `(?=)` checks, but doesn't captures what is has checked. But when `()` used inside, what is matched by it is captured.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying. I need it to be PCRE2 compatible and all "text2" on the line to be matches and not group captured.